# problems updating store 4.0 to 4.1 in EE 5

Tags: expresso-store

the upgrades/updates always seem broken.  The ’update” button in the CP never seems to process and recognize that the update is done.  I’ve beein running v 3.1 on two sites since earlier this year..  As far as I can tell, they are fully updated to v 3.1, yet the CP still shows the “update to 3.1” button.  And, now, the same thing  on another install going from v 4.0 to v4.1.

Looking through the update notes, doesn’t appear to be any DB updates.

So, I’m also assuming the v4 > v4.1 update is complete (all files are copied and the store seems to operate correctly).  Just seems that the “update the version in the DB so we know what version we’re running”  process is not working.  Can I (should I) just increment the version numbers in the DB tables associated with Store?

Comment: Hi - have same issue on a V4.3.6 site.  I think there is a bug in the installer somewhere.  Have lodged a support request with VMG so hopefully they'll work it out and release an updated version soon.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a display issue. As long as you have the latest files in place, you have the latest version and don't need to worry about the older version showing up there. We'll look to fix that in a future update.